# Passing value to outer function from inside Runnable

Tags: java, android

i am using this code in my android app where I call a function userExists() from within MainActivity which is a different class. Here's my code:

```
public boolean userExists(Member m){
    final String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '"+m.getEmail().toString()+"'";
    Log.d("InsideUserExists", "Member "+m.getEmail()+" and "+m.getPassword());
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final boolean value;

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            Log.d("userExists", Integer.toString(new Query().getUserQuery(sqlQuery)));
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception caught while getting "+e);
            }
        }

    });
    th.start();
    return false;
}
```

Here's how I am calling this function from my MainActivity:

```
public void generateQR(View v){

    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,QRGenActivity.class);
    final EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    final EditText mPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Member m = new Member(mEdit.getText().toString(),mPass.getText().toString());

    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        protected  String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(new Functions().userExists(new Member(mEdit.getText().toString(),mPass.getText().toString()))){
                return "done";
            } else return null;
        };

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result!=null){
                Log.d("ProceedWithIntent","Proceed to get to next activity");
                intent.putExtra("emailValue", mEdit.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("password", mPass.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
    }.doInBackground(mEdit.getText().toString(),mPass.getText().toString());


}
```

My question is, as you can see, userExists() has to return type "boolean" and I am querying for the user using `new Query().getUserQuery(sqlQuery)` which returns an int depending on if there are any records or not, however, this is inside Runnable().

How do I pass this integer value from getUserQuery() function call to outer userExists() method so that it can return true or false depending on the int value.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use this runnable in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Since creating a Thread in another thread, there is no easy way to just synchronously provide a return value without blocking `userExists()`. You will either need to move the `Runnable` code out into `userExists()` and have it block, or use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do work in the background and handle the result elsewhere later.

I would suggest looking at the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. It allows you to do an operation in the background, and use a caluclated result on the calling thread.